# Are there any downsides to dual citizenship?

Tags: citizenship

I am a US citizen from birth.  I may be able to get German citizenship due to my ancestors, if I file all the proper forms.  Are there any downsides to dual citizenship?  Other information: I am married with adult children, also US citizens, and do not plan to have more children.  I have no financial dealings outside the USA.

Comment: Dual citizenship means dual rights and dual duties. Want to serve in the German army? And you'd have to change your cute little avatar image which would be considered very, very offensive by Germans.

Comment: @gnasher729 I wonder whether you are aware that Germany does not currently have active military conscription, or that the default avatar images are generated automatically by an algorithm.

Comment: @phoog  Great to hear that Germans would find my (automatically generated) avitar offensive.

Comment: @gnasher729   Automated computer products can reflect and even perpetuate very negative ideas. Do you happen to know how I can change my avitar.

Comment: Technically, you don't "get German citizenship due to my ancestors" -- you either already have German citizenship (and have had it since birth) by descent, or you don't have it and can't get it through any ancestors (other than an exception for people born to German mothers before 1975). It's just a question of whether you get proof of such citizenship (which you already have) or not.

Comment: Becoming a dual citizen of the U.S. in addition to some other country where someone primarily has their affairs can have downsides because the U.S. taxes its citizens on worldwide income which few other countries do, potentially resulting in double taxation.

Comment: Nearly a year later, it occurs to me that I should have referred you to [Expatriates.SE], where you're more likely to find helpful information about the practical implications of dual citizenship.